# ASP.net c# simple query paramter question

Tags: c#, asp.net, parameters, parameter-passing

```
        // Add into DB
        using (tblArtworkTemplatesTableAdapter tblAdapter = new tblArtworkTemplatesTableAdapter())
        {
            tblAdapter.Insert(DateTime.Now, "@specID");
            "@specID" = int.Parse(lstChooseSpec.SelectedValue)
        }
```

I know the code is wrong, just for illustration of my objective, how do I paramatise the input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally it depends. If You are using any kind of ORM like LINQ to SQL or NHibernate, it will do it for You no questions asked. If YOu are doing it using Plain ADO objects (which I suppose is the case) then You will have to comeup with the Command (or SQLCommand or any other ICommand implementation) object and use SQLParameter class (or other parameter classes).

ICommand has the collection of parameters that You can arbitralily edit.

```
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
            "select * from STH where column = @SpecID", conn);

    //it might be useful to specify a type as well
    SqlParameter param  = new SqlParameter();
    param.ParameterName = "@SpecID";
    //I woudl use the TryParse method though
    param.Value         = int.Parse(lstChooseSpec.SelectedValue);

    cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
```

Comment: I'm using DAL, do I need to worry about paramatising inputs or will it do it for me?

Comment: Well it depends on the DAL. I do not know the API. Generally DAL do it for You they only require passing the regular C# data values and they care of parametrisation themselves

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
"@specID" = int.Parse(lstChooseSpec.SelectedValue)
```

Is incorrect. You can't assign a value to a constant. You might mean something like

```
specId = int.Parse(lstChooseSpec.SelectedValue);
```

The rest of the code is confusing. Why are you parsing `lstChooseSpec.SelectedValue` to an integer, then trying to add it to the adapter as a DateTime? C# is strongly-typed: something is either an `int` or a `DateTime`, but cannot be both.

It might help if you could post the rest of the method.

[Also, have a look at this overview on MSDN.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tthwx.aspx)

Comment: I'm trying to insert two values, first is DateTime, the second is an integer.  I want to make the second input into the insery query a parameter to avoid SQL injection